# action perform on text filed data entered through bar code scan

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox

We have a text box which will fill from bar code scanning. I need to perform an action immediately once the bar code scanned to the text box. Without any enter click or button press. How can I achieve it. ?

Comment: `_TextChanged() ` did the job for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an **enter** action happening with each scan while using scan gun, so by handling the enter action this can be achieved.